# jQuery plugin bsmSelect doesn't update its values when it is called again and its select options have changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [bsmSelect](https://github.com/vicb/bsmSelect) jQuery plugin. Basically, what it does is changing the way a select-multiple is rendered to make easier to pick up the options. It hides the select element and shows a list instead.

So, first of all I'm applying the plugin function to my select-multiple element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  $('#my_select_multiple').bsmSelect({
    plugins: [$.bsmSelect.plugins.sortable()],
    title: 'Add',
    removeLabel: 'Remove'
  });
  ...
});
```

On the other way, I have another select element (this one is simple) which has an ajax request bind to its change event. This ajax request get new `#my_select_multiple` options depending on the select simple value. Ajax response is the new HTML for `#my_select_multiple` options. So I have:

```
function getNewOptions(val) {
  var r = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: /*My URL*/
  }).responseText;
  return r;
}

...

$(document).ready(function() {
...
  $('#my_select_simple').change() {
    $('#my_select_multiple').html(getNewOptions($(this).val()));
  }
...
});
```

AJAX is working as expected. New options are got correctly and they are inserted into `#my_select_multiple` (which is hidden by bsmSelect plugin, but I can check it with Firebug). But bsmSelect didn't realize new changes and doesn't get updated.

So, I think what I want is to reapply `$('#my_select_multiple').bsmSelect();` with its new options.

I've been looking around a little bit and here is what I have tried.

**1.** I've tried to call again the funcion with the `success` and `complete` (one at time) of the AJAX request. Didn't work:

```
function getNewOptions(val) {
  var r = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: /*My URL*/,
    success: function() { $('#my_select_multiple').bsmSelect(); }
  }).responseText;
  return r;
}
```

**2.** I've tried to bind the function with the `on` jQuery function. Didn't work:

```
$('#my_select_simple').on('change', function() {
  $('#my_select_multiple').bsmSelect();
});
```

**3.** I've tried 1 and 2 removing previosly the HTML generated by bsmSelect. Didn't work.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:** The exact code

First I have a `global.js` file which apply bsmSelect plugin to some select multiples (`.quizzes`):

```
$('.quizzes').bsmSelect({
  plugins: [$.bsmSelect.plugins.sortable()],
  title: 'Add',
  removeLabel: 'Remove'
});
```

And then, in the php file I define the `updateQuizzes` function and bind it to the select simple (`project_id`) change event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateQuizzes(project_id) {
    var r = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
url: '<?php echo url_for('event/updateQuizzes')?>'+'<?php echo   ($form->getObject()->isNew()?'':'?id='.$form->getObject()->getId()).($form->getObject()->isNew()?'?project_id=':'&project_id=')?>'+project_id,
    success: function() { $('.quizzes').bsmSelect({
      plugins: [$.bsmSelect.plugins.sortable()],
      title: 'Add',
      removeLabel: 'Remove'
    }); }
  }).responseText;
  return r;
  }

  $('#project_id').change(function(){
    $('.quizzes').html(updateQuizzes($(this).val()));
  });
</script>
```

As I told, the AJAX request works without problems, but not the calling bsmSelect the second time...

Comment: please add your current HTML to your question, and what is returned from your ajax request.

Comment: Hey @Patricia, tha AJAX response is ok, it's what is expected. The problem is that function `bsmSelect()` is not called again. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, all of this is a problem with bsSelect plugin... I tried with another plugin and it worked well. So I will update my question, even I think it'll be very difficult to get an answer for such specific problem. I'll open a ticket in bsmSelect tracker as well.

Comment: does your plugin have a remove or destroy function?  you could try removing your backing drop down list and adding a new one and applying the plugin to it instead of just updating the content and re-applying the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [I opened a ticket](https://github.com/vicb/bsmSelect/issues/18) and bsmSelect developer has answered me in minutes. Great!

To let bsmSelect know about its select changes, you have to trigger a `change` event on the select. There is no need to call bsmSelect again.

So it can be that way:

```
function loadNewOptions(val) {
  var r = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: /*My URL*/,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#my_select_multiple').html(data).trigger('change');
    }
  }).responseText;
  return r;
}

$('#my_select_simple').change(function() {
  loadNewOptions($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what the problem is, but you could try

```
$('#my_select_simple').change() {
    $('#my_select_multiple').html(getNewOptions($(this).val())).trigger('change');
}
```

This triggers a change event on select_multiple, and might fire bsmSelect. I'm not sure what the problem here is exactly, but that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: But this wouldn't do the AJAX request, didn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set your HTML in the `success` of the Ajax call, something like:

```
function loadNewOptions(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: /*My URL*/,
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#my_select_multiple').html(data).bsmSelect(); 
        }
    });
}
```

And then calling like:

```
$('#my_select_simple').change() {
    loadNewOptions($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Even setting the html in the Ajax call it didn't work... :( Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#my_select_simple').change() {
    $('#my_select_multiple').load("your Url", function(){
        $('#my_select_multiple').bsmSelect();
    });
  }

});
```

something like this should work.

`.load` will put whatever your url returns into `#my_select_multiple`

the first parameter is the url to load, and the 2nd is a function to call when it is done.  which is where you need to set up your fancy selector.

Comment: It didn't work :( I think this is another way of doing the AJAX request. But the function call has no effect, neither here or in the success parameter in my function. Thank you anyway

Comment: yea, load just uses ajax in the background.  but it troubles me to here you say it didn't do anything.  can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Hey @Patricia. The Ajax request does work, it sends back the expectet response... but the function call doesn't work. I updated my answer with the code. Thank you.